# How to add list to dictionary by using index of list as key and item of list as value?

Tags: python

Question:
Given a `list` named `list1` and a dictionary named `dict1`, using "For" loop to write code to add all items of `list1` to `dict1` by using the index of the `list` as the key of the dictionary and the item of the `list` as the value of the dictionary.
for example:

```
`    list1 = ["a","b","c"]`

`    dict1 = {7:"d",8:"e",9:"f"}`
```

after running your code, `dict1 = {7:"d",8:"e",9:"f",0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"}`

My Code:

```
`dict1 = {7:"d", 8:"e", 9:"f"}
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
ii = 0
for i in [dict1]:
    dict1[ii] = list1[ii]
    ii = ii + 1
    print(dict1)`
```

2nd attempt after 1 desperate hour of trying:

```
`for i in list1:
    if i not in dict1.keys():
        dict1[0] = list1[0]
        dict1[1] = list1[1]
        dict1[2] = list1[2] 
        print(dict1)`
```

I'm lost!

Comment: I think you need the enumerate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
>>> list1 = ["a","b","c"]
>>> dict1 = {7:"d",8:"e",9:"f"}
>>> dict1.update(dict(enumerate(list1)))
>>> dict1
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f'}
```

or

```
>>> dict(dict1.items() + list(enumerate(list1)))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f'}
```

Comment: omg thanks! but how do I make it such that `dict1 ={7:"d",8:"e",9:"f",0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"}`?